# Auto add to cart a Gift product variation programmatically in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

I'm trying to create a buy one get one offer for *woocommerce* when someone adds a product to the cart. The code below works but only with simple products, I've tried adding the variation `ID` to the variable but it does not work. Any ideas? thanks to the community

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bbloomer_add_gift_if_id_in_cart' );
 
function bbloomer_add_gift_if_id_in_cart() {
 
   if ( is_admin() ) return;
   if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return;
 
   $product_bought_id = 421;
   $product_gifted_id = 1256;
 
   // see if product id in cart
   $product_bought_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_bought_id );
   $product_bought_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_bought_cart_id );
 
   // see if gift id in cart
   $product_gifted_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_gifted_id );
   $product_gifted_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_gifted_cart_id );
 
   // if not in cart remove gift, else add gift
   if ( ! $product_bought_in_cart ) {
      if ( $product_gifted_in_cart ) WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $product_gifted_in_cart );
   } else {
      if ( ! $product_gifted_in_cart ) WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_gifted_id );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a product variation to cart you need the parent variable product id and the product variation Id (both).

Now the code that you are using is obsolete and will not work if customer update cart in cart page, removing the required product id. In this case, the Gift product will be removed after reloading the page or jumping to another page. So `template_redirect` is not the right hook to be used.

Try the following instead, that handle simple products and product variations too:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'wc_auto_add_gift_to_cart' );
function wc_auto_add_gift_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;
    
    $required_product_id = 37; // The required product Id (or variation Id)
    $parent_gift_id      = 40; // The parent variable product Id (gift) for a product variation (set to zero for simple products)
    $product_gift_id     = 41; // the variation Id or the product Id (gift)
    
    $has_required = $gift_key = false; // Initializing
    
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Check if required product is in cart
        if( in_array( $required_product_id, array($cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id']) ) ) {
           $has_required = true;
        }
        // Check if gifted product is already in cart
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $product_gift_id ) {
           $gift_key = $cart_item_key;
        }
    }
    
    // If gift is in cart, but not the required product: Remove gift from cart
    if ( ! $has_required && $gift_key ) {
        $cart->remove_cart_item( $gift_key );
    }
    // If gift is not in cart and the required product is in cart: Add gift to cart
    elseif ( $has_required && ! $gift_key ) {
        // For simple products
        if( $parent_gift_id == 0 ) {
            $cart->add_to_cart( $product_gift_id );
        } 
        // For product variations (of a variable product)
        else {
            $cart->add_to_cart( $parent_gift_id, 1, $product_gift_id );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I've successfully used the code you posted in this answer, now I want to expand on it. Is there a simple way to change the $required_product_id to an array of categories where the product must be in, instead of one product ID? Or does that require a totally different approach?

Comment: Also I tried to change `$required_product_id = 37;` to an array like this: `$required_product_id = array (37, 38, 39);` (with the idea that any of those product IDs would trigger the gift to be added to the cart), it didn't throw an error but  the gift didn't get added for any of the product ids I put in the cart. How to change the required product ID to an array of possible IDs?