# woocommerce - add item to cart if any item from multiple categories is in cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

I have found a code which adds a free gift programatically to the cart when a specific product is added to the cart, the answer code of this question: [Auto add to cart a Gift product variation programmatically in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001875/auto-add-to-cart-a-gift-product-variation-programmatically-in-woocommerce/64005117#64005117), I want to modify it to put a free gift in the cart when any of a series of products is in the cart. Preferably any product from a specified array of categories.

I have not much understanding how to go about this.

I made an array out of the first parameter (of category IDs not product IDs) and the next step would be to change the loop to find any product IDs in the specified categories and check if any of those products is in the cart.

I found a piece of code which lists all product IDs inside a category which is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_echo_product_ids' );
 
function bbloomer_echo_product_ids() {
   $all_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids',
   ) );
   foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {
        echo $id;
   }
}
```

But I don't know how to combine this code into the original code to make the loop go through all product IDs inside the category IDs which I specified.

Comment: If you don't really make significant changes to an existing answer code just adding the link in your question is enough. Now we expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and correcting my question. I edited it now to not just ask for a solution but show what I tried to do myself and get directions to understand the answer and not just get a copy/paste solution.