# Adding item to woocommerce cart programatically not working for translated site

Tags: php, woocommerce, foreach

I have added a code snippet in my functions PHP file which ads a free gift in the cart every time something with the product-tag "catalog" is in the cart. The original code comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001875/auto-add-to-cart-a-gift-product-variation-programmatically-in-woocommerce/64005117#64005117) by LoicTheAztec for adding 1 gift based on 1 required product.

I have modified the code to work instead of one required_product_id to take any product with specified tag as a required product. On my English (default) website this seems to work fine but for some reason on my translated site (using [WPML](https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/)) I get an error message "you cannot add another (gift)" (each time I add something new in the cart which has the required tag this message appears again). Also, on the translated website, the gift does not remove itself when the required product(s) are removed from the cart.

I am not sure what I should change in the below code to make it work also for translated pages. The error that you cannot add another indicates that it is trying to do it twice... but I am at a loss in terms of how to fix it...

Here is the full code with the adjustments I did:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'wc_auto_add_dvd_gift_to_cart' );
function wc_auto_add_dvd_gift_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;
    
    //$required_product_id_0 = 40223; // (use prodID to include all variations)
    $parent_gift_id_0      = 0; // The parent variable product Id (gift) for a product variation (set to zero for simple products)
    $product_gift_id_0     = 92271; //the variation Id or the product Id (gift)
    
    $has_required = $gift_key = false; // Initializing
    
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Check if anything with tag "catalog" is in cart
        if( has_term( array('catalog'), 'product_tag', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
           $has_required = true;
        }
        // Check if gifted product is already in cart
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $product_gift_id_0 ) {
           $gift_key = $cart_item_key;
        }
    }
    
    // If gift is in cart, but not the required product: Remove gift from cart
    if ( ! $has_required && $gift_key ) {
        $cart->remove_cart_item( $gift_key );
    }
    // If gift is not in cart and the required product is in cart: Add gift to cart
    elseif ( $has_required && ! $gift_key ) {
        // For simple products
        if( $parent_gift_id_0 == 0 ) {
            $cart->add_to_cart( $product_gift_id_0 );
        } 
        // For product variations (of a variable product)
        else {
            $cart->add_to_cart( $parent_gift_id_0, 1, $product_gift_id_0 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I get an error message -> you cannot add another (gift)"_ - Where in your code is that message generated? I only see that your code adds or removes products to/from the cart.  So this looks more like a conflict with another custom code or a plugin you're using

Comment: Forgive me if it is obvious, but I do not know where in my code this is generated. I have "learned" to code based on trial and error and by picking pieces of code from here and there... My functions.php file has over 50 pieces of custom-code. Do I need to disable one by one to see what is causing the conflict or is there some easier way to find the cause?

Comment: You can look in other code snippets, if you are already using the same hook. In any case, your question cannot be answered as it is currently written, since it concerns a conflict and is therefore very specific